# CSS - Share a gradient with multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I'm trying to create a gradient that starts at a first div and ends at the last div.

Much like the Instagram Messaging App:

[image: Instagram]

I tried using [Multiple.js](https://multiple.js.org/) but I was unable to get it to work:

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<div class="messageRow messageRowFromRecipient">
 <div class="message messageFromRecipient">
  <div class="messageContent">Hello!</div>
   <div class="messageTimestamp">8:54 PM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried running this javascript code with `Multiple.js` but nothing happen.:

```
var multiple = new Multiple({
  selector: '.messageFromRecipient',
  background: 'linear-gradient(#273463, #8B4256)'
});
multiple.update();
```

So now I'm wondering, is there a pure javascript/css method to achieve this? Could anyone advice please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must not have included the links to the *multiple* CSS and Javascript properly. In the below snippet you can see your code working as expected...

```js
var multiple = new Multiple({
  selector: '.messageFromRecipient',
  background: 'linear-gradient(#273463, #8B4256)'
});
// multiple.update(); /* not required */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple.js/0.0.1/multiple.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple.js/0.0.1/multiple.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="messageRow messageRowFromRecipient">
 <div class="message messageFromRecipient">
  <div class="messageContent">Hello!</div>
   <div class="messageTimestamp">8:54 PM</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="messageRow messageRowFromRecipient">
 <div class="message messageFromRecipient">
  <div class="messageContent">Hello!</div>
   <div class="messageTimestamp">8:54 PM</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="messageRow messageRowFromRecipient">
 <div class="message messageFromRecipient">
  <div class="messageContent">Hello!</div>
   <div class="messageTimestamp">8:54 PM</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="messageRow messageRowFromRecipient">
 <div class="message messageFromRecipient">
  <div class="messageContent">Hello!</div>
   <div class="messageTimestamp">8:54 PM</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="messageRow messageRowFromRecipient">
 <div class="message messageFromRecipient">
  <div class="messageContent">Hello!</div>
   <div class="messageTimestamp">8:54 PM</div>
  </div>
</div>
```